# Push notifivations stop to work after few minutes

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, push

I have very strange behavior of APNS in my app. All my certificates, profiles etc is configured correctly and I actually can receive push notifications if I run my app first time on the device. But after few minutes they stop to come.
If I delete my app from device and run again from project, notifications come but only during short time. Then I have to delete it again, install again and so on...
I'm very wondering with this proplem. As I know there is no limitation to send push notifications and device token does not have expiration date (even if has,
few minutes are too short).
I have this first time and have no idea what a reason it can be...

Comment: What type of push, foreground or background?

Comment: Yes there are limitations for Push, when you frequently send push, there are messages may drop or override with new ones if last was not delivered. Plus make sure you are sending correct token for push, remember there are different token for prod and dev environments. Another thing you need to make sure you are using Prod and dev correctly etc.. all depends..

Comment: Both. I'm handling both modes. But it does not matter.

Comment: Read [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) for listed reasons why notifications may not work.

Comment: I know about this. I was waiting about 10 minutes after last notification. But it didn't help. They don't come anymore... Thanks for doc. I will read it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have called the fetching notifications methods not from

`func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

This is one method of App Delegate which will always be called when your application launches, [image]

Check out the descriptions of these methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is incomprehensible. What does it mean and what has it got to do with the problem? There's no such thing as a fetching notifications method.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I think problem is not that. I am registering for notifications in didFinishLaunchWithOptions. And after I run application I do nothing in the code, and do nothing with the app on the device. Just sending notifications for test. But after few minutes they just don't come...

Comment: With that I meant howsoever he is setting up the connection or configuring. While I was using FCM, my notifications would arrive only when the app was in background. Maybe LembergSun made the same mistake.

Comment: That's not at all clear in the answer ;-)   That's the  expected behavior, a push sent to the user is only displayed if the app is not in the foreground, if the app is in the foreground the push is sent to the app instead, then the app can decide if it needs to notify the user.

Comment: Notification arrives in whatsapp if you are chatting with one person and someone else sends you a message. So notifications can arrive when the app is in foreground.

Comment: I never said the notification don't arrive, I said they get delivered to the app. The app can then post a local notification which to the user looks identical to a push notification. But anyway, whapsapp uses voip pushes.